# Not able to add new line in file

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a file using these functions:

```
json_decode = json.loads(any_content)
json_decode = byteify(json_decode)
```

After some processing of the any_content, I extract specific tags of JSON to `script1` and `scriptOrigin`.

```
script1 = json.dumps(script1)
script2 = []
    for i,j in scriptOrigin:
        j = "#" + j + "\n"
        script2.append(j)
```

I want to use these to write to `path1`.

```
def function(script1, path1, script2):
   writeArrayToFile(script1, path1, "a")
   writeToFile("\n", path1, "a")
   writeToFile(script2, path1, "a")

def writeToFile(content, path, mode, breakBy=None):
  try:
     print "content is: " 
     print content
     print type(content)

     outputFile = open(path, mode)

     try:
        if breakBy:
            outputFile.write(content + breakBy)
        else:
            outputFile.write(content)
        outputFile.close()

     except IOError as e:
       print 'Trouble writing to file'

  except IOError as e:
     print 'Trouble opening file'

def writeArrayToFile(array, path, mode):
  for item in array:
      item = "\n" + item + "\n"
      writeToFile(item, path, mode, "\n")
```

I want the script to output something like this:

```
123
abc
etc
```

However, what I get is this:

```
123abcetc
```

When I print out the strings, they do show up with lots of newlines. However when it comes to the content of the file, it becomes one line.

I have tried different default applications for the file that is being edited -- I have tested Visual Studio, WordPad, and NotePad, but they all did not make a difference.

I have also tried to add in `\r\n` instead of simply putting `\n`. This made no difference either.

Comment: how do you call function? I see a lot of newlines in file

Comment: Are you opening it in notepad? If so, try another text editor. I have the occasional newline issues with notepad. if this fixes it then you need `\r\n` which is a carriage return and a newline.

Comment: sorry, im new to python. could you elaborate more on how do you call the function? I added many new lines in the file because they were not being displayed so I was testing if it would display.

Comment: I am working on Visual Studio (and I am unable to use anything else because of the nature of my project)

Comment: Sorry, I am working on Visual Studio, I made a mistake. I have the code opened in Visual Studio, but are you suggesting that I change the computer's setting to open the file to be edited in a different text editor?

Comment: the `\r\n` did not work

Comment: The default application that is set for the edited file is Visual Studio

Comment: I changed it to wordpad but still one line is being produced!

Comment: Hmm that's odd. It prints the newlines for me although it doesn't look like your example. What are you inputting?

Comment: @SirParselot, you should only ever write `\n` python will convert this to the proper line separator value for the system it's running on. You might see on windows if you write `\r\n` you get `\r\r\n` in the output file.

Comment: @shuttle87 I've had to use `\r\n` before in order for the newlines to appear in notepad. I've heard what you just said before and it doesn't always seem to work for me. 99% of the time I have no issues but there's that 1% when it breaks. Also I use python 2.7 if that has anything to do with it

Comment: This is the unwanted outcome: `#include <EngduinoLEDs.h>#include <SPI.h>void setup(){EngduinoLEDs.begin();} void loop(){EngduinoLEDs.setAll(WHITE);}`

Comment: @SirParselot if you have the write parameter as "wb" it will do that, was that the case where it broke?

Comment: I am running a Microsoft machine, so it should have \r\r\n, but it displays nothing!

Comment: @EimiOkuno you really need to give us an example of how you call this code in the case where it breaks.

Comment: @shuttle87 I have added more code, I hope this helps.

Comment: You need to show exactly the code that calls `writeArrayToFile` along with the parameters calling this function in the case where it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I had an extra json.dumps(any_text) that made everything, even lines that had \r\n to one line.

So for example a\r\n1 will be processed as:

a
1

However if the text was taken to be processed again, it then became:

a1

Thanks for all the help!